# How do I keep printed words in list form?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list "d" that looks like this:

```
d={{{1,4},{1,1},{1,2}},
{{1,4}},{1,1},{3,3}}}
```

I also have the following code:

```
For[b = 1, b <= MaxIt, b++, {
  w = Table[
     If[
      d[[b, l]][[1]] == d[[b, l]][[2]],
      Print["Same"],
      Unevaluated@Sequence[]],
     {l, 1, Length[d[[b]]]}];
  }]
```

List "d" is composed of two generations, each row makes up a single generation.  When I run the above loop, I get printed outputs of the word "Same" every time the two numbers in a sublist are the same.  The issue is I cannot tell which "Same" refers to which generation.  Is there any way to keep my printed words in list form so that they would read `{{Same},{Same,Same}}`(as in the case above, generation 1 only has 1 same and generation 2 has two sames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {{{1, 4}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{1, 4}, {1, 1}, {3, 3}}};
```

You can [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) the function [`SameQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html) at `Level` 2  to get the result without a loop:

```
Apply[SameQ, d, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{False, True, False}, {False, True, True}}
> ```

You can process this list using `ReplaceAll` to replace `False` with `Nothing` and `True` with `"Same"`:

```
Apply[SameQ, d, {2}] /. {False -> Nothing, True -> "Same"}
```

> ```
>  {{"Same"}, {"Same", "Same"}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you for showing me that. I hate to be a bother but is it still possible to do it the way I had done it above?  Although I can use the new method you showed me for one part of what I'm doing, I have a section of code that's a little more complicated and is sort of "stuck" in the form similar to what I had shown above.  Would you happen to know of a way to do that?

Comment: @D'Angelo, try `w = {};
For[b = 1, b <= Length@d, b++, 
 AppendTo[w, 
  Table[If[d[[b, l]][[1]] == d[[b, l]][[2]], "Same", 
    Unevaluated@Sequence[]], {l, 1, Length[d[[b]]]}]]]; w`?

Comment: There's an error saying that Part specification 1[[1]] is longer than depth of object

Comment: @D'Angelo, try `d = {{{1, 4}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{1, 4}, {1, 1}, {3, 3}}};` as input (`d` in your post has a typo.).

Comment: That fixed it, thank you so much